# Make git commit open vim in insert mode

Tags: vim, git

Everytime I enter `git commit -a` vim opens in normal mode and I often enter unwanted commands. Is there a way to make git open vim in insert mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit exec 'au VimEnter * startinsert'
```

Here's a layout of how it works:

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit                                  " Whenever we open a 'gitcommit' file,
                           exec 'au VimEnter * startinsert' " Run the following command:

au VimEnter               " Whenever vim opens,
            *             " Any type of file
              startinsert " Enter insert mode
```